# Visual Studio 2010 missing option for new project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, new-project

I opened our Visual Studio 2010 Professional and noticed that I do not have an option New>.. the only options I have are:

New Team Project (not what I want to use, I simply want a new project)
Connect to Team Project
New File (looked and didn't see an option for New Project)
Open File..

I also tried resetting all settings to default by using Tools> Import and Export Settings> Reset all Settings.

Any ideas?

Much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: So I found out that I need the "Business Intelligence Tools" that are installed using add/remove features for SQL Server 2008 (I am running 2012 and don't have this option). Also in case you have the same problem, you will need to add " SQL Server Data Tools".

Helpful post I found: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b19526d7-60a8-4fde-929e-8c4f8dfd7244/ssrs-visual-studio-2010-report-server-project-template

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/deb6aee1-8c16-4f5b-bffb-f2fc08bd12ae/business-intelligence-development-studio-2010-download

Answer (score 0):

Alright so this did it for me:

1. I had to add SQL Server Data Tools to my SQL Server 2012 installation (done by adding/removing features)
2. Downloaded [Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)
3. Downloaded SQL Server Data Tools - [Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843) 
   (I know it says 2012 but according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027) it says that you need to download either VS 2012 or VS 2013 since they no longer support the SSDT for 2010.

I found [this](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/04/ssdt-installation-confusion/) very helpful when researching the entire problem, it highlights scenarios that work and that don't work as well as what to do to remedy the situation.

I really hope that this helps anyone in the future with the same problem I had. Let me know :)

Comment: [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027 [2]: http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/04/ssdt-installation-confusion/